# Global TLS algorithm policies for java servers

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

My team is currently going through all of our applications and enforcing strict TLS algorithm policies for various application **servers**. Since we don't have any control over some of the applications we connect to, we cannot enforce the same policies when acting as a client. For Java applications, we figured it'd be easiest to implement this globally in the java.security file rather than updating each app individually to do the right thing. That would also make future updates much easier.

I see that many of the options in the java.security file allow for differentiation between server settings and client settings with the "usage TLS(Server|Client)" constraint, but jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms doesn't seem to utilize those. Looking around, I don't see any simple way to globally apply a list of algorithms only for server (listening) connections.

Do any of you know if there's an easy way to do this?

Note: We're aware of simple settings for spring boot applications and things of that nature, but we're hoping to find something that can set an appropriate cipher whitelist or blacklist for **all** applications, including third party applications that use the JRE.